# Tracking Page visits with specific term in url in Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am using Google Tag to load my Google Universal Analytics code.

Is there a way to track visits to pages that contain specific term in their url?

For example, tracking vistis to a page that contain the word `video`, like this: `https://example.com/video`

I researched this point but can't find a suitable option in the "campaigns" or "reports" sections.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You can add a condition to a pageload trigger so it fires only when the url (or the path, rather) contains a specified phrase.

Go to the "variables" section and make sure that in the "built-in variables" section "Page Path" is showing (else click "configure" and activate the var). Page path will hold the path, i.e. everything after the domain name (for "https://example.com/video" the path will be "/video").

Then go to "triggers", click "new" and select "Page Load" as trigger type. Activate the radio butto that says "fires on some page loads". In  the form that appears set the first dropdown to "Page Path", the second to "contains" (or "equals" or "ends with", depending on your requirements), hit save and attach the trigger to your tag.

[image]